# How to access Padrino model and database in a "standalone" (bin/) script?

Tags: ruby, padrino

In my Padrino App I define model classes that I want to use from a script in `bin/` without actually serving something (e.g. pre-populate database with a command line tool).

How can I access the model classes and database? I digged around the `padrino console` and tried with

```
Padrino.mounted_apps.each do |app|
  puts "=> Loading Application #{app.app_class}"
  app.app_obj.setup_application!
end
```

but to no avail, I keep getting

```
bin/gusy_fill:13:in `<main>': uninitialized constant Seminar (NameError)
```

errors. I start bin/gusy_fill with `bundle exec bin/gusy_fill` and `Seminar` is the name of a model, referenced like

```
puts Seminar.all
```

in `bin/gusy_fill`. I have a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26213806/how-to-access-a-gemified-padrino-apps-model-from-other-gem-that-requires-that-app) about how to do this from a different gem.

Comment: @dario posted an awesome answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26213806/how-to-access-a-gemified-padrino-apps-model-from-other-gem-that-requires-that-app , which includes solutions to this question too. I will merge when tested.

Comment: I rephrased the other question slightly. The answer matches. Will mark as dupe now.